# Is Corelle Ware considered glass or ceramic

Tags: kashrut-kosher

Theoretically if someone accidentally use my dairy dish for meat or vice versa and it's a Corelle Ware dish does he need to throw it out or can he consider it to be like glass?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33686/pyrex-prep-bowls-meat-and-dairy/33689#33689

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Star-K](https://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/1162/a-crystal-clear-halachic-approach-to-glass/) Corelle is considered as glass.

[Ohr.Edu](https://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/38/Q1/) quoting Rabbi Scheinberg says that it has the same Halacha of regular glassware.

Comment: http://halachayomit.co.il/en/default.aspx?HalachaID=4337 and https://oukosher.org/blog/kosher-professionals/lo-basi-ella-lorer-glass/ corroborate this approach, as well.